# Codename on Build error

Tags: build, codenameone

When I tried to build my app I receive this error:

```
C:\bt\IOS_Catedral\build.xml:92: Compile failed; see the compiler error output for details.
   at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Javac.compile(Javac.java:1180)
   at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Javac.execute(Javac.java:935)
   at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
  at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
  at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
  at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:435)
  at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:456)
  at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1393)
  at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1364)
  at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
  at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1248)
  at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.runBuild(Main.java:851)
  at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.startAnt(Main.java:235)
  at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.start(Main.java:198)
  at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.main(Main.java:286)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
  at com.intellij.rt.ant.execution.AntMain2.main(AntMain2.java:30)
  Ant build completed with 4 errors and one warning in 2s at 23/01/2016 10:59 AM
```

This was re4ceived building for IOS from an W7 PC, similar errors was received for Android and Windows Phone.

How can I build an app?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The errors should be listed above/below those lines, you only posted some of the output. If you scroll up/down there you will see the full error log.

Comment: I have nothing. I attached a capture of the message

Comment: my line 92 is this:    classpath="${javac.classpath}:${build.classes.dir}">

Comment: I saw this : error reading C:\bt\IOS_Catedral\lib\CLDC11.jar; error in opening zip file

Comment: There is a button on the side there that will let you see the actual compiler output instead of that tree.

Comment: Cant see it, the app works on the simulator, but when I try to build it I get this

Comment: I find it, Is the button toggle tree or text to find the errors